# Spark2 dataframe get difference of two tables, with some exclusion

Tags: java, apache-spark

Lets say I have two tables, tableA and tableB, they have the same schema. Now Id like to get the mismatch of the two tables with the same primary key but with some exclusion of some column values.

So, if either table ref column contains xx, we consider this would match with the other table column value. Can anyone help me with this in java? I had a hard time reading scala code

```
tableA 
+--+------+------+------+
|id| name |  type|  ref | 
+--+------+------+------+
| 1|aaa   |     a|    a1| 
| 2|bbb   |     b|    xx|
| 3|ccc   |     c|    c3| 
| 4|ddd   |     d|    d4| 
| 6|fff   |     f|    f6| 
| 7|ggg   |     0|    g7| 
+--+------+------+------+

tableB
+--+------+------+------+
|id| name |  type|  ref | 
+--+------+------+------+
| 1|aaa   |     a|    a1| 
| 2|bbb   |     b|    b2|
| 3|ccc   |     c|    xx| 
| 5|eee   |     e|    e5| 
| 6|fff   |     f|   f66| 
| 7|ggg   |     g|    g7| 
+--+------+------+------+    
Expected results:
+--+------+------+-------------+
|id| name |  type|         ref | 
+--+------+------+-------------+
| 6|fff   |     f|   [f6 ->f66]| 
| 7|ggg   |     0|   [0 -> g7 ]| 
+--+------+------+-------------+
```

This seems working fine, but I dont have strong confidence of it.

```
Dataset<Row> join = data1.join(data2, data1.col("id").equalTo(data2.col("id"))
        .and(data1.col("name").equalTo(data2.col("name")))
        .and(data1.col("type").equalTo(data2.col("type"))
        .and(data1.col("ref").equalTo(data2.col("ref"))
        .or(data1.col("ref").equalTo(lit("xx")))
        .or(data2.col("ref").equalTo(lit("xx"))))), "left_semi");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `UDF (User Defined Functions)` to achieve this once you have joined your two dataframes like below:

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val df1 = Seq((1, "aaa", "a", "a1"), (2, "bbb", "b", "xx"), (3, "ccc", "c", "c3"), (4, "ddd", "d", "d4"), (6, "fff", "f", "f6")).toDF("id", "name", "type", "ref")
val df2 = Seq((1, "aaa", "a", "a1"), (2, "bbb", "b", "b2"), (3, "ccc", "c", "xx"), (4, "ddd", "d", "d4"), (6, "fff", "f", "f66")).toDF("id", "name", "type", "ref")

val diffCondition: UserDefinedFunction = udf {
  (ref1: String, ref2: String) => {
    var result: String = null
    if (!ref1.equals(ref2) && !"xx".equals(ref1) && !"xx".equals(ref2)) {
      result = s"$ref1 -> $ref2"
    }

    result
  }
}

df1.join(df2, Seq("id", "name", "type"))
  .withColumn("difference", diffCondition(df1("ref"), df2("ref")))
  .filter("difference is not null")
  .show()
```

and the output is

```
+---+----+----+---+---+----------+
| id|name|type|ref|ref|difference|
+---+----+----+---+---+----------+
|  6| fff|   f| f6|f66| f6 -> f66|
+---+----+----+---+---+----------+
```

Comment: @HuaLiang you can try on your own, its just basic method calls, if still facing issues then let me know

Comment: seems your solution is fixed on ref column, what about type column could goes wrong as well. I've updated the description, can you help? thansk

Comment: also, if the udf has more than 3 parameters, I have : Resolved attribute(s) name#11,type#12 missing from amount error

Comment: the solution given as per the previous question description assuming that there is only one column to check, in case if u have such multiple columns then you need to handle in the join condition and UDF